# Can you share a component pouch with another creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment

Can a wizard with a component pouch share their component pouch with another spellcasting player character?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. By any chance, is your question answered by [this similar question about material components](/questions/80271)?

Comment: I think you may also need to remove the houserule reaction of sharing from this and just ask if you can share components. if it's directly related to the houserule, then it's kind of up to you/your DM. If you separate it, we can answer it within the existing rules.

Comment: I've removed the 2nd question, but you can always [roll back](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/142159/edit) the edit.

Answer (score 13):

## Nothing in the rules says they can't

> A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus [...] in place of the components specified for a spell. [Basic Rules, Casting a Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Components)

There is no special requirement that the pouch by magically bound or attuned or otherwise restricted to one person using it. It is just a pouch full of ingredients and there is no rules reason why you cannot share it with another spellcaster.

## Location, location, location

However, do note that the pragmatics and action economy of such an arrangement is likely to be tricky.

> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell's material components — or to hold a spellcasting focus [...] [Basic Rules, Casting a Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Components)

Firstly, you have to keep the pouch somewhere where you both can access it since you need to physically hold it in order to use it. If one of you goes to cast a spell with material components but can't reach the pouch, that person is going to be in a tricky spot and potentially unable to cast it.

Next, depending on how and where you store it, you might have to use your free object interaction to get to it:

> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action. [Basic Rules, Combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn)

You may even have to use an action to access it depending on how the DM rules transferring the item between two characters would work in your exact scenario.

> The DM might require you to use an action for any of these activities when it needs special care or when it presents an unusual obstacle. [Basic Rules, Combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn)

But all this means is that it isn't an ideal arrangement but it is all fine according to the rules. However, I would highly recommend getting a pouch for each of you at the soonest opportunity.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason why components can't be shared. The rules only state that the caster must have a hand free to access the material component (so they must presumably be somewhere easily accessible to both wizards).

See also rules for interacting with objects.

[Other Activity on Your Turn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn)

[Use an object action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UseanObject)